# Как решить decimal.InvalidOperation на сервере?

Tags: python, django, docker, decimal

Инфо: Есть сайт-фронт на реакте, с сайтом-бэком на джанго. При оформлении заказа сваливается 500 с ошибкой InvalidOperation at /api/orders/
[<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Дополнительна инфо: При переносе обоих сайтов на локальный тестовый сервер все работает, на ливе же проблемы с decimal. Контейнеры одни и те же, код один и тот же

Принятые меры: Строки вида

```
round(Decimal((obj.total_price * 100)) / discount_revers - Decimal(obj.total_price), 2)
```

преобразовывал в

```
round(((Decimal(obj.total_price) * Decimal(100))) / discount_revers - Decimal(obj.total_price), 2)
```

но эффекта не возымело. Также, перезапускал контейнеры, как на ливе, так и на тестовом, с тем же эффектом.

Вопрос: можно ли решить эту проблему, и если да, то как?

Comment: Вы знаете строку исходного кода (вашего, а не библиотечного!) на которой возникает ошибка? Если знаете - вставьте перед ней печать значений переменных, распечатайте окружающий код и переделайте вопрос. Сейчас вопрос - ни о чём...  Нужна **конкретная** информация.

Answer (score 0):

`round()` в качестве аргумента принимает вещ.число (`float`) и операции между `Decimal`  и `float` невозможны. Вам нужно привести их к одному виду

```
Decimal(round(float(obj.total_price) * 100 / float(discount_revers) - float(obj.total_price), 2))
```